# How to post form, from layout view using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, entity-framework

I am trying to insert data by form inside bootstrap modal.

**What I am doing?** Since it's in main layout view, I have created modal for register user. Once it's done, I made controller with view for register. Once it's `scalfold`, I have copied HTML of create page form inside my layout bootstrap modal.

I have mentioned `controller name` and `action name` to post data. but on <kbd>submit</kbd> it says resource not found.

**Question:** What Should I use to let it find resource from layout view?

**My Front-end-Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AlluringDecors.Models;

namespace AlluringDecors.Controllers
{
public class FrontendController : Controller
{
    private AlluringDecorDB db = new AlluringDecorDB();

    // GET: frontend
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
        //db.Registers.ToList()
    }

    public ActionResult about()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult accompolished()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult contact()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult FAQ()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ongoing()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult services()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult upcoming()
    {
        return View();
    }


    // Register: Models

    // GET: Registers


    // GET: Registers/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Register register = db.Registers.Find(id);
        if (register == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(register);
    }

    // GET: Registers/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Registers/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "uid,fname,lname,uaddress,uphone,uemail,upassword")] Register register)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Registers.Add(register);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(Index);
    }

    // GET: Registers/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Register register = db.Registers.Find(id);
        if (register == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(register);
    }

    // POST: Registers/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "uid,fname,lname,uaddress,uphone,uemail,upassword")] Register register)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(register).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(register);
    }

    // GET: Registers/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Register register = db.Registers.Find(id);
        if (register == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(register);
    }

    // POST: Registers/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Register register = db.Registers.Find(id);
        db.Registers.Remove(register);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
 }
```

**My Layout view Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade login" id="loginModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog login animated">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login with</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="social">
                                <a class="circle github" href="/auth/github">
                                    <i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a id="google_login" class="circle google" href="/auth/google_oauth2">
                                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a id="facebook_login" class="circle facebook" href="/auth/facebook">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="division">
                                <div class="line l"></div>
                                <span>or</span>
                                <div class="line r"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="error"></div>
                            <div class="form loginBox">
                                <form method="post" action="/login" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                                    <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                                    <input class="btn btn-default btn-login" type="button" value="Login" onclick="loginAjax()">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="content registerBox" style="display:none;">
                            <div class="form">
                                <div class="row">
                                 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "FrontendController", FormMethod.Post ))
                                 {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                                            <h4>Register</h4>
                                            <hr />
                                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.uaddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.uaddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.uaddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.uphone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.uphone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.uphone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.uemail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.uemail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.uemail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.upassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.upassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.upassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    }
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="forgot login-footer">
                        <span>
                            Looking to
                            <a href="javascript: showRegisterForm();">create an account</a>
                            ?
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forgot register-footer" style="display:none">
                        <span>Already have an account?</span>
                        <a href="javascript: showLoginForm();">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just change  `Html.BeginForm("Create", "FrontendController", FormMethod.Post )` to `Html.BeginForm("Create", "Frontend", FormMethod.Post )`

Comment: Please also refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - the key word being **Minimal** (99% of what you have shown is irrelevant to your question)